# Why is Javascript adding function name in a displayed array element

Tags: javascript, arrays, inheritance

I have a weather application written in Javascript that consists of a Temperature constructor function (among others). Without getting into details, I noticed a very weird behavior that makes my application crash. When I create an array of Temperature objects and add an object to it, then display it in a console and then replace with a new Temperature object (which has the same data) and again display it in a console, it shows it differently. This is my code:

```
let weatherData = [];
weatherData[0] = new Temperature(200);
console.log(weatherData[0]);
weatherData[0] = new Temperature(200);
console.log(weatherData[0]);
```

This is the console output:

```
Temperature {
  value: 200,
}
{
  value: 200,
}
```

Because of this, I cannot use methods that the Temperature inherits from another class, when I add object to an array for the first time. This is what I mean:

```
let weatherData = [];
weatherData[0] = new Temperature(200);
weatherData[0].inheritedMethod();
```

/\ throws error weatherData[0].inheritedMethod() is not a function

```
let weatherData = [];
weatherData[0] = new Temperature(200);
weatherData[0] = new Temperature(200);
weatherData[0].inheritedMethod();
```

/\ works fine

Could someone explain to me why this is happening and how can I fix it?

Temperature class:

```
//inherits from WeatherData
const WeatherData = require("./WeatherData");

module.exports = function Temperature(time, place, type, unit, value) {
  WeatherData.call(this, time, place, type, unit, value);

  Temperature.prototype = Object.create(WeatherData.prototype);
  Temperature.prototype.convertToF = function () {
    ...
  };
  Temperature.prototype.convertToC = function () {
    ...
  };
};
```

Comment: Without seeing the code for `Temperature` it's going to be hard to say.

Comment: Please show where the `Temperature` class was defined. See [mcve].

Comment: Also, it's not *JavaScript* that's doing that, it's the console API. The console API can be a source of a lot of frustration until you get used to what it does.

Comment: The `Temperature.prototype` stuff should probably go outside the Temperature function. It would probably save you a lot of time to use the `class Temperature extends WeatherData` syntax instead though.

Comment: ^^ this. Each time you create a new instance, a new prototype object is created. That is destructive.

Comment: consider turning this into the newer [JS `class` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) so you don't run into the problem of "how do I define/link up prototypes" in the future, where your current module export becomes `module.exports = class Temperature extends WeatherData { constructor() { ... } convertToF(temp) { return ... } convertToC(temp) { return ...} ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All this trouble is caused by executing the following code within the constructor:

```
  Temperature.prototype = Object.create(WeatherData.prototype);
  Temperature.prototype.convertToF = function () {
    ...
  };
  Temperature.prototype.convertToC = function () {
    ...
  };
```

This should be placed outside the constructor, so that it executes immediately and only once.

### Difference in console output

First of all, the console is free to display objects in its own way. Still, the two objects have a significant difference: the first one was created at a time when the above assignments to `Temperature.prototype` were not yet made, so the `this` object that was implicitly created when you executed `new Temperature()` was still made from the original `Temperature.prototype`.

However, by the time you created the second instance, the `Temperature.prototype` had already changed, and that directly influences how `this` is constructed. It is now constructed with `WeatherData.prototype` as prototype.

See the difference in this snippet:

```js
// Set up
function WeatherData(time, place, type, unit, value) {
    if (time !== undefined) this.time = time;
}
WeatherData.prototype.inheritedMethod = function() {};

function Temperature(time, place, type, unit, value) {
    WeatherData.call(this, time, place, type, unit, value);  
    // Wrongly positioned code:
    Temperature.prototype = Object.create(WeatherData.prototype);
    Temperature.prototype.convertToF = function () {};
    Temperature.prototype.convertToC = function () {};
};

// test case:
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(new Temperature(200)).constructor.name); // Temperature
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(new Temperature(200)).constructor.name); // WeatherData
```

### Error `.inheritedMethod()` is not a function

Since the first instance was created at a time when the prototype object was still the original `Temperature.prototype`, and the inheritance from `WeatherData` was not yet set up, that instance has no inheritance from `WheatherData`, and by consequence, it does not have `inheritedMethod` in its prototype chain.

Here we check one level up in the prototype chain, and find that in the first case that level is `Object`. Only in the second case we have `WeatherData` as constructor:

```js
// Set up
function WeatherData(time, place, type, unit, value) {
    if (time !== undefined) this.time = time;
}
WeatherData.prototype.inheritedMethod = function() {};

function Temperature(time, place, type, unit, value) {
    WeatherData.call(this, time, place, type, unit, value);  
    // Wrongly positioned code:
    Temperature.prototype = Object.create(WeatherData.prototype);
    Temperature.prototype.convertToF = function () {};
    Temperature.prototype.convertToC = function () {};
};

// test case:
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(new Temperature(200))).constructor.name); // Object
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(new Temperature(200))).constructor.name); // WeatherData
```

## A long story short

All this to say that these assignments should not have happened in the constructor, but outside of it.

Things are a lot easier with the more modern `class ... extends` syntax:

```js
// Set up
class WeatherData{
    constructor(time, place, type, unit, value) {
        if (time !== undefined) this.time = time;
    }
    inheritedMethod() { console.log("inherited method called") }
}

class Temperature extends WeatherData {
    constructor(time, place, type, unit, value) {
        super(time, place, type, unit, value);
    }
    convertToF() {};
    convertToC() {};
}

// test case:
new Temperature(200).inheritedMethod();
new Temperature(200).inheritedMethod();
```